# Ruby NoMethodError // Telegram Bot

Tags: ruby

I'm using this Ruby code for running Telegram messenger bot. After code is runned with `/start` command, it crashes with the following error:

```
./bot.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from ./bot.rb:20:in `loop'
        from ./bot.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:41:in `block in fetch_updates'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:37:in `each'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:37:in `fetch_updates'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:29:in `listen'
        from ./bot.rb:17:in `block in <main>'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:22:in `run'
        from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/telegram-bot-ruby-0.3.11/lib/telegram/bot/client.rb:10:in `run'
        from ./bot.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

Bot code is here:

```
require 'telegram/bot' 
token = '...' 
require 'net/http' 
url = URI.parse('http://api.wotblitz.ru/wotb/clans/info/?application_id=...&clan_id=8') 
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s) 
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| 
   http.request(req) 
   } 

require 'json'
str = JSON.parse(res.body)
ids = str["data"]["8"]["members_ids"]
n = 0
m = ids.size - 1
players = ''
Telegram::Bot::Client.run(token) do |bot| 
    bot.listen do |message|
        case message.text
        when '/start' 
        loop do 
           url = URI.parse('http://api.wotblitz.ru/wotb/account/info/?application_id=...&account_id=' + ids[n].to_s)
             req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.to_s) 
             res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) {|http| http.request(req) 
             }
             str1 = JSON.parse(res.body)
             nick = str1["data"][ids[n].to_s]["nickname"]
             players = players + nick + "\n"
            n += 1
            break if n == m
        end
        bot.api.sendMessage(chat_id: message.chat.id, text:"#{players}")
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mudasobwa no, it is on line 26 `str1["data"][ids[n].to_s]["nickname"]`

Comment: @Зелёный I don't know how to fix this

Comment: something here `str1["data"][ids[n].to_s]["nickname"]` return the `nil`, maybe `str` or `ids`, to debug it is an easy way, add `puts str` after `str1 = JSON.parse(res.body)` and check output.

Comment: Could you share the results of `JSON.parse(res.body)`? It seems that is missing the "data" key

Comment: @Зелёный trouble is that it crashes after first run. When I run code at first, there is no errors.

Comment: @NickGnd no, it isn't missing "data"

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this same issue, I found a hacky fix for it. When running this code from my macOS terminal, I get the **undefined method 'run'** message. When I run it inside my vscode terminal on the other hand, it works correctly. I had this same issue on a Linux machine aswell. It probably has something to do with how my environment is setup.

Hope this helps someone out.